# Force between charged hemispheres

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

The question has been asked before, but most of the questions I found were for solid spheres. I'm asking about a hollow sphere/shell. Also, I'm not looking for a calculation. I have a conceptual question. If the field inside the sphere is zero everywhere, shouldn't the force be zero on every part of the sphere? Does the sphere have to be solid in order for such a force to exist? Basically, my argument is that the sphere does not act on itself with a force. However, that's the field inside. The field at the surface is defined and is equal to $\frac{kq}{R^2}$. But that field, according to my understanding, shouldn't act with a force on the object producing it. Am I wrong about these conclusions? Does it make sense to ask about the force of the northern hemisphere on the southern hemisphere in the case of a hollow spherical shell?

Answer (score 1):

No, the sphere doesn't have to be solid for there to be a nonzero force. Each little piece of the surface of the sphere would have to be bound to its neighbors to keep from flying away. In reality, we could have a thin metal shell in which each little piece is staying together because of molecular structure in the material, or we could have tiny pieces of charge that are glued to a paper shell, and we'd want to know how strong the glue needs to be for each tiny piece to stay on.

The notion of a self-force isn't clear, so it can be easier to chop the sphere like you suggested; you mentioned top and bottom, I'll split it into a tiny piece of the sphere's charged surface $(a)$ and the rest, a sphere with a small hole,  $(b)$.

The quantity for the field at the surface is exactly the coefficient to the force that a point charge, $Q$, on the surface of the sphere would feel.

$$
F_{sphere\xrightarrow{} {point}} = QE = Q \frac{kq}{R^2}
$$

This is the idea we wield to take existing concepts of force and "test charge" to define the $E$ field. But instead of a point charge, $Q$, we have this tiny piece of spherical shell $(a)$, which if taken sufficiently small amounts to no charge so that $(b)$ still has $q$ overall, but we can pretend that it's really, really small but non-zero in size and has charge ${\rm{d}}Q=
sigma {\rm d} A$, charge desnity, $\sigma$, area ${\rm d} A$ so that the force it experiences is small, but proportional to the $E$ field with the same relationship as before,

$$
{\rm d} F = {\rm d}Q\;E = \sigma\,{\rm d}A\; \frac{kq}{R^2}
$$

Now, with some manipulation, it becomes clearer that it may make more sense to talk about the amount of force per unit area,

$$
\frac{{\rm d} F}{{\rm d} A}= \sigma \frac{kq}{R^2}
$$

So this is how we'd have to approach little bits, but it's fairly extensible. Since each little bit of force would point away radially, we can use this to talk about the net force that the top of the sphere exerts on the bottom.

If we cut into two hemispheres, we can answer the question of "if I had two identical hemispheres each with net charge $Q/2$, how much force would I have to apply to keep them together?